# Parsing strings before character in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to obtain the environment, project name and location from a string and store it in a variable in Powershell.
The string is in the format of `env-project-location`. Example`uat-hrapp-westeurope`

How do I filter the string and store the outputs in a variable?

```
$environment = "uat"
$project = "hrapp"
$location = "westeurope"
```

Comment: I have removed the [tag:regex] tag from your question to avoid further down-votes, I believe this was a valid question to ask and does not deserve to be down-voted without any kind of feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Santiago Squarzon's post got me thinking so I did a little googling and found that you can also use this method if you want a PSCustomObject vs independent variables.

```
Clear-Host
$Base = "uat-hrapp-westeurope"
$CFSArgs = @{PropertyNames = "Environment", "Project", "Location"
             Delimiter = '-'}
$obj = $Base | ConvertFrom-String @CFSArgs
$Obj
```

Output:

```
Environment Project Location  
----------- ------- --------  
uat         hrapp   westeurope


PS> $obj | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
Environment NoteProperty string Environment=uat        
Location    NoteProperty string Location=westeurope    
Project     NoteProperty string Project=hrapp
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex for this, assuming the string will always have the same naming convention a simple [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0) would do it:

```
$environment, $project, $location = 'uat-hrapp-westeurope'.Split('-')
```

Comment: Santiago, thanks for that, I didn't know you could use Split in that manner.

Comment: @RetiredGeek FWIW it's a function of the output type (`[string[]]`), not the method itself - you can assign any expression that evaluates to multiple values to multiple variables: `$one,$two,$many = 1..10`

Comment: @RetiredGeek I didn't know either, being here help us learn right :)

Comment: This works too! But when naming conventions are different, it gets messy. I implemented @RetiredGeek answer. :)